# Can you use Native Storage on Ionic 1?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-nativestorage

I see there is a Native Storage on Ionic 2, but I didn't see a Native Storage for Ionic 1 and wasn't sure if I was just missing it, or if it didn't exist.

I'm aware of Sql lite, and other similar solutions, but I was hoping to avoid having to add that in to our app if we didn't need it, since we're going to eventually move to Ionic 2, but we have an immediate need for persistent storage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can use it. It is a cordova plugin.

Just use `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-nativestorage`

And then you can use :

```
NativeStorage.setItem("reference", obj, setSuccess, setError);
```

See the docs : https://github.com/TheCocoaProject/cordova-plugin-nativestorage

Comment: I've tried that and NativeStorage is always undefined, I double checked that I have NativeStorage in both my config.xml, and in my package.json.  I'm using version 2.1.0, but I can't seem to ever get it to work, I don't get any errors loading or anything, it just acts like it's not there at all.

Comment: Never mind, I realized that I had to expclitly tell TypeScript to find it on window, since typescript doesn't automatically use window for references. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use localstorage, this works well with andoid and ios devices and its very light weight

```js
value = angular.toJson(value);
$window.localStorage.setItem(key, value);
```

Comment: localstorage isn't always persistent, see this plugin: https://github.com/TheCocoaProject/cordova-plugin-nativestorage